# Matching association rule to source records

Tags: r, apriori, arules

I use the following code and receiving the appropriate association rules:

```
library("arules")
data("Adult")
    rules <- apriori(Adult,parameter = list(supp = 0.5, conf = 0.9, target = "rules"))
  labels(rules)
```

There are 50 rules.
I would like to go back to the source data:

```
Adult3<-as.data.frame(as(Adult,"matrix"))
```

And to add new column to `Adult3$RUL_NUM`. This column will include the value of relevant rule (from 1 to 50 in this case) that the record complies with (for each record). If there are more than one rule per record I would like to add the last rule that record complies with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to look into the is.superset function. For example

```
is.superset(Adult, lhs(rules))
```

will give you a logical matrix that indicates for each transaction which rule is "relevant" (i.e., where all the items in the LHS are present).

**Edit:** If you want to match the whole rule then use the code Avi suggested below:

```
is.superset(Adult, lhs(rules))
```

To get the id (number) of the last rule that matches you can use (more or less) straight-forward R code on the superset matrix:

```
w <- sapply(apply(is.superset(Adult, rules), MARGIN = 1, which), tail, n = 1)
```

This code finds the column index of all ones in each row and then returns the last one.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I would like just to add number (1 to 50 the number of rules in this case) to each row of data (Adult in this case). The number is the relevant rule to the specific line. Can your solution provide the specific rule number to each line?

Comment: Michael, I think your solution should be altered. Since for the same LHS there can be different RHS. And I would like to match for each line the rule that matches it (as if we run a select in sql for each rule and see for each line if it is a subset of it). Some rules have same LHS but different RHS and we need to take this into account. So I think your solution should be is.superset(Adult, (rules))

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael! It works! I have 2 remarks. My source file contains 1712 lines (1713 with headline) and it is a dataframe I converted it to transactions, and used:  w <- sapply(apply(is.superset(mytrans, rules), MARGIN = 1, which), tail, n = 1) then I converted w back to dataframe: df <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(w), byrow=T),stringsAsFactors=FALSE) However now I have only 1256 lines. I think the gap (456) is because of source lines with no appropriate rule -  named integer(0). Is there a way to keep in df the original lines number with space value in case of missing rule number?

Comment: @Avi: I did not think about that. I think you need to replace the integer(0) with NA before you do the unlist.